# Got an error on association for my ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Here's the stack:

undefined method `class_name' for nil:NilClass Did you mean? class_eval

```
    def redirect_based_on_shift_state
         redirect_to new_shift_call_list_path(created_shifts) if current_user && created_shifts = current_user.shifts.in_state(:created).first
    end

    Class < User
         self.primary_key = 'guid'
         has_many :shifts, foreign_key: 'user_guid', primary_key: 'guid'

    Class < Shift
         belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_guid', primary_key: 'guid
```

I already added class_name in each model to specify it explicitly though I am not using different class name. Hoping that will fix the problem however did not. This happens after my ruby upgrade from 2.2.1 to 2.5.1 and run bundle update --conservative. 
Thanks for the help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbNKg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHSxK.png)

Comment: Can you add the stack-trace? We currently have no idea where *class_name* is called.

Comment: What I can tell you is adding the method *class_name* to each model doesn't impact the result because it is called upon `nil` (eg. `nil.model_name`) and not on one of your models.

Comment: Here's the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbNKg.png

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with operator precedence. Try moving the `created_shifts` assignment to a separate line.

```
def redirect_based_on_shift_state
  return unless current_user
  created_shifts = current_user.shifts.in_state(:created).first
  return unless created_shifts
  redirect_to new_shift_call_list_path(created_shifts)
end
```

This makes it also easier to find the issue in case the error still occurs. By having you logic on multiple lines the stack pointing to a certain line is also more accurate, since there is less happening per line.

Comment: Hi thanks I tried that but the error is somewhat the same, https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHSxK.png

Comment: I guess something is wrong in the *in_state* scope. Can you post its contents?

Comment: include Statesman::Machine

      state :new, initial: true
      state :created
      state :in_progress
      state :updating
      state :canceled
      state :expired
      state :assigned
      state :error

Comment: Just to isolate the issue, does `Shift.in_state(:created)` also produce this error?

Comment: when I do inspect in current_user.shifts.inspect I get this ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []

Comment: Shift.in_state(:created) does not produce this error but throws undefine method for 'shift'

Comment: @Mr.Sinko The empty collection proxy means that *current_user* doesn't have any shifts. It's somewhat strange that *in_state* is not available for the class itself, most query methods are. Try `Shift.all.in_state(:created)` instead. This calls *in_state* on the current query scope instead of calling it on the *Shift* class itself.

Comment: the error still persist after trying shifts.all.in_state(:created).first

but here's the new output of the console
User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`guid` = 'fff54dd0-207e-475b-9bc9-4bef3c97f821' LIMIT 1
  Shift Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `shifts`.* FROM `shifts` WHERE `shifts`.`user_guid` = 'fff54dd0-207e-475b-9bc9-4bef3c97f821'

before just User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`guid` = 'fff54dd0-207e-475b-9bc9-4bef3c97f821' LIMIT 1

Comment: I forgot to add the additional association in my shift model where the state is might be included.  

include Statesman::Adapters::ActiveRecordQueries
  attr_accessor :start_date, :start_timer, :end_date, :end_timer

  has_many :shift_requests
  has_many :employees, through: :shift_requests
  has_many :shift_transitions
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: 'user_guid', primary_key: 'guid'

Comment: it was weird that the in_state stop working after the stateman gem was updated to 3.5.1 before it was 2.0.1. I had to undone the upgrade of that gem.

Comment: @Mr.Sinko What Rails and Ruby version are you using? [The Statesman changelog says that v3.0.0 dropped support for Rails 4.2 and dropped support for Ruby 2.2.](https://github.com/gocardless/statesman/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v300-3-july-2017)